# checking items in a list and take a decision

Tags: c#

I want to build a program in Windows forms where the user can create a pizza by pressing buttons.

My problem is that when the user presses an ingredient more than once, the list will just increment. I tried various methods but they don't seem to work.

I have seen a solution using a for loop checking individual items in the list however I will have to implement that 19 times which is not really efficient (once for every button)

```
string check = "Thin Base";
        if (My_Pizza.Contains(check))
        {
            My_Pizza.Items.Remove("ThinBase");
            My_Pizza.Items.Add("Thin Base");
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "ThinBase" and "Thin Base". Not the same thing.

Also, if an item is already in the list, you don't need to do anything. Simply invert your check

```
string check = "Thin Base";
if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(check))
{
    My_Pizza.Items.Add(check);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General idea is not to hardcode string values, but create reusable method that will do what you need: check if certain value is already in the list and if it not, add this item to list. This will help you to avoid duplicate code.

In the button event handler you simply call this method and provide string value as parameter. I'm not sure how exactly you handle button clicks, but I would suggest creating single reusable method once again and acquire string value from button.Text property.

Here is code sample for you to demonstrate the idea.

```
    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) sender;
        if (clickedButton != null)
        {
            string buttonContent = clickedButton.Text;
            CheckAndAdd(buttonContent);
        }
    }

    private void CheckAndAdd(string valueToCheck)
    {
        if (!My_Pizza.Items.Contains(valueToCheck))
        {
            My_Pizza.Items.Add(valueToCheck);
        }
    }
```